# Amazon S3 bucket naming convention

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wonder, what is the reason behind two different naming conventions for buckets created in US regions and the other regions available in AWS.

According to this document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html we should name our buckets using the rules:

> In all regions except for the US Standard region a bucket name must
>   comply with the following rules. These result in a DNS compliant
>   bucket name.
>
> Bucket names must be at least 3 and no more than 63 characters long
>
> Bucket name must be a series of one or more labels separated by a
>   period (.), where each label:
>
> Must start with a lowercase letter or a number
>
> Must end with a lowercase letter or a number
>
> Can contain lowercase letters, numbers and dashes
>
> Bucket names must not be formatted as an IP address (e.g.,
>   192.168.5.4)

For the US region tho, we can use longer names, dots, dashes, underscores etc.

I do understand that making your bucket with non dns compilant name maybe a bad idea but I don't get why in US region its available and in others not. What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Here's an update from AWS on the [naming conventions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html) in the US Standard region going forward: "While the US Standard region currently allows non-compliant DNS bucket naming, we are moving to the same DNS-compliant bucket naming convention for the US Standard region in the coming months."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`US Standard` is different in many aspects from other S3 regions.

The bucket naming restrictions are probably different because `US Standard` is the oldest S3 region. It's possible that they later decided that it is better to enforce DNS compliant bucket names in other regions and kept `US Standard` unchanged for compatibility reasons.

`US Standard` is also different when it comes to storage and consistency as it's the only region that doesn't provide read-after-write consistency and that spreads the storage across a wider geographical area, between Northern Virginia or the Pacific Northwest.